# How to adjust a div to not move when other sibling is faded out

Tags: html, css

There is a bid div (`leftBox`) that holds to divs inside: `LeftBox-InnterTop` and `LeftBox-InnterButtom`. The first inner div has 90% height and the other one has 10%. Normally the first inner div (`LeftBox-InnterTop`) is hidden, and fade in when mouseover in the general div.

My problem is the class `LeftBox-InnterButtom` goes to top when the sibling div is hidden. It is supposed to stay at the bottom of the box. How can I make it to stick to the bottom even when the other dive is hidden?

Here is the CSS and HTML code:

```
.leftBox {
float:left;
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:url(http://goo.gl/Z3Escd);
}
.LeftBox-InnterTop {
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50);
}
.LeftBox-InnterButtom {
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="leftBox">
        <div class="LeftBox-InnterTop">
            <div class="SmallBoxes"></div>
            <div class="SmallBoxes"></div>
            <div class="SmallBoxes"></div>
            <div class="SmallBoxes"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="LeftBox-InnterButtom"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/danials/X7VTE/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using fadeIn() and fadeOut().  Just change `visibility` via css.  This way the element is not removed from the page structure: http://jsfiddle.net/X7VTE/11/.

By the way, what you are trying to do can be 100% implemented in CSS.  There is no need to use jQuery.

Comment: Nice one! I didn't think about that solution. I just used jQuery to have the Fade effect.

Comment: In many instances, it is much better to go the browser route.  Your effects will use less resources and will require less code.  Here's CSS-only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/X7VTE/12/.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following styles to your boxes :

```
.leftBox {
   position: relative;
}
```

and

```
.LeftBox-InnterButtom {
   position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

See the updated fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/X7VTE/6/

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS `position: absolute` for that, so the position of the element is fixed inside the container, here's what you need

```
.LeftBox-InnterButtom {
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
    position: absolute;  // this will make the element position fixed inside it's container
    bottom: 0; // this will make the position at the bottom
}
```

and give either

```
position: relative
```

or

```
position: absolute
```

to the container, so the `position: absolute` for the child element will be relative to it's parent, in this case  `.LeftBox-InnterButtom` inside `.leftBox`

here's the working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/X7VTE/5/)

Comment: Good answer, but it should be mentioned that the parent container should have a position absolute or relative to ensure that it is the offset parent.

Comment: @Nathaniel it's already mentioned below the code, but maybe it's should be written in code to

Answer (score 1):

If 'LeftBox-InnterButtom' will always be at the bottom, then you should probably use 'position: absolute;'

http://jsfiddle.net/s49p6/

```
.mainBox {
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    background:black;
    position: relative;
}
.LeftBox-InnterButtom {
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```